# misidentified usb headset as xbox gamepad in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio, xbox-one

There is a known bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1639408 for USB wireless Afterglow AG9+ Wireless headset that is being misidentifed as a generic xbox pad (on mine ubuntu 18.04). In fact this is rather a generic usb sound card or sort of. Is there any way/workaround I can try to make it work without waiting for the bugfix?
Tried to read something about udev rules etc (wanted to manually set this device as generic usb soundcard) but it looks like I know to little about the topic to think up something useful. Would be grateful for any tips.

Comment: commented out the bug report with more details, if more is needed please let me know or point some faq which procedure should I follow, thanks